# Need help in incrementing the date in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, date

Error thrown as "Invalid number" while trying to increment the date. Given below is the query executed through sqlplus. Please help me on this.

```
select ''''||to_date(:To_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy')+1||'''' from DUAL;
```

Expected output (if ***`:To_date`*** variable is `'09-DEC-2014'`):

**`'10-DEC-2014'`**

Answer (score 1):

Note the extra brackets.

```
SQL> variable d varchar2(100);
SQL> exec :d := '09-DEC-2014';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select '''' || (to_date(:d, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1) || '''' from dual;

''''||(TO_DATE(:D,'D
--------------------
'10-DEC-14'
```

Changing date format:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY';

Session altered.

SQL> select '''' || (to_date(:d, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1) || '''' from dual;

''''||(TO_DATE(:D,'DD-
----------------------
'10-DEC-2014'
```

Comment: To change the format of a value the usage of a function would be more appropriate than changing the settings of the whole session an use an  impliciat conversion. So use ` select '''' || to_char(to_date(:d, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1,'DD-MON-YYYY') || '''' from dual`

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation is occurring before the addition causing it to fail trying to add a string to a number.  Concatenation and addition both have the same level of [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators001.htm), but are processed from left to right, so if you had removed the leading concatenation, the trailing one would succeed.  As Balazs explained, adding parenthesis fixes the order of execution problem, but it is still doing implicit date to string conversion in a format that depends on the session settings.

As miracle173 pointed out, the best solution is to make your code independent of session settings by doing explicit date conversion as follows:

```
SELECT'''' || to_char(to_date('09-DEC-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 1,'DD-MON-YYYY') || '''' 
FROM dual;
```